# Get the Admin label of a configurable option value

Tags: configurable-product

Working in a product view template (.phtml) I am trying to get the Admin label for a configurable option value. I have managed to `var_dump` the front end values:

```
$productAttributeOptions = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);

$attributeOptions = array();

foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {

    foreach ($productAttribute['values'] as $attribute) {

        $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label']][$attribute['value_index']] = $attribute['store_label'];
    }
}

var_dump($attributeOptions);
```

This gives me an array:

```
array (size=1)
  'Configurable Option' => 
    array (size=2)
      378 => string 'Black' (length=5)
      379 => string 'Pink' (length=4)
```

Which is all fine and dandy. But how would I go about getting the "Admin" values for these options? The reason I would like to do this is because the admin values will contain hex colours that I can use to show a colour for a visitor to select instead of just having a drop down.

Any help is muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have using this at frontend,then you cannot easy get those option.
Get need to use option collection and filter the option collection by Attribute id and option  ids.

### Get Option ids:

Get option list from your code:

```
    $productAttributeOptions = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);

$attributeOptions = array();
$attributeList=array();
foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {


    foreach ($productAttribute['values'] as $attribute) {
        $attributeList[$productAttribute['attribute_id']][]=$attribute['value_index'];

        $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label']][$attribute['value_index']] = $attribute['store_label'];
    }
}
```

### get Admin label:

then call eav option collection then filter collection by option is

```
 foreach( $attributeList as $key=>$value){
    $attributeId=$key;
    $options=array_unique($value);
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection');
                $collection->getSelect()->where('main_table.option_id IN (?)',$options);
                $collection->setPositionOrder('asc');
                $collection->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                ->setStoreFilter(0);
            $collection->load();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($collection->toOptionArray());

}
```

**and 0 for store admin**

Answer (score 0):

Optimized Code:

PASS THE ATTRIBUTE ID AND OPTIONID TO THE below query - this will easily get the admin label of the corresponding attribute.

```
$attributeid = ''; // here pass the attributeid
$optionId = ''; //here pass the optionid


$query = "SELECT IF(tsv.value_id > 0, tsv.value, tdv.value) AS value FROM eav_attribute_option AS main_table
        INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option_value AS tdv ON tdv.option_id = main_table.option_id
        LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value AS tsv ON tsv.option_id = main_table.option_id 
        AND tsv.store_id = 0 WHERE (attribute_id = {$attributeid}) AND (tdv.store_id = 0) and (tsv.option_id = {$optionId})";
```